# Bar plot displaying black instead of colored bars

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

For some reason, MATLAB is not plotting the bars in blue in the specified color format. They keep appearing as black.
Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
%create an example dataset with negative and positive numbers
data=[-500:300];
figure
bar(data.*(data>0),'r')
hold on
bar(data.*(data<0),'b')
```

Comment: Why did you ask this [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295052/specified-color-for-a-bar-chart-is-ignored)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only seeing the black outlines of many densely packed blue bars. If you zoom in you can see this. The outlines seem to be added automatically to the second bar plot. If you reverse the order of `r` and `b` you can see this.

The quickest fix would be to make the last line:

```
bar(data.*(data<0), 'b', 'EdgeColor', 'b');
```

And don't forget to `hold off` at the end.